Accessing AWS Transcribe Stream as a Frontend Client
Second post on here today. Curious to know if anyone has a smart method of allowing a frontend client to access AWS Transcribe's Live Transcription Stream service, without making API keys visible to the frontend.
I've funnelled other AWS Services in my webapp thru Lambda functions authorized by Cognito via a Gateway REST API. I feel like this is a bit more complicated since this is a stream? Uncharted waters for me.
Any recommendations for how to do this? Ideally use AWS Gateway's REST?
Thanks a ton.
